# Help with "Rush the net"

Tags: meaning, dictionaries

> It didn’t feel any more disjunctive than seeing Suzanne Lenglen rush the net in a full-length dress in say, 1916.

Hey guys! I did not get meaning of "rush the net" exactly. Any idea? Thanks a million.

Answer (score 1):

She was a champion tennis player in the years 1914-1926.  Here she is rushing the net in the attire of the time:

[image]